# Unhandled Expcetion C++ - VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

If a `std::exception` is thrown from my code, Test Explorer will just show "Message: Unhandled C++ Exception". It does show the proper stack trace though.

Is it possible to have Test Explorer show the message from the `what()` method of `std::exception`?

Answer (score 0):

what method will only tell you the name of the exception. may be there is some method like stack trace similar to java.